# Find log files of Linux Mint after system turned frozen

Tags: linux, linux-mint, logging

My system freezes regularly, more than once a day, sometimes right after the start of X. I have not been able to reproduce the error deterministicly.

After rebooting, where do I find the old files? Which are most likely to be relevant?

Addendum:

- My system is a desktop computer.
- According to temperature measurement, there is no overheating.
- I currently use a 32-bit OS. Recycled the drive of my old computer.
- Linux 3.2.0-23 generic (i868)
- Intel Core i3-3225
- 8 GB RAM - no errors according to ram test on first 4 gb.
- Gigabyte h77-d3h mainboard (ivy brigde)
- No graphic card installed
- 350 W power device.
- I use an old dvd-drive together with an whatever2sata-converter.
- The LAN box of my machine does not react, so I suppose the mainboard is defunct, but I want to be sure.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Run: `sudo dmesg` to see recent kernel messages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the error. For `X`-related errors, files of interest are:

```
~/.xsession-errors
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

You may also find useful information about various errors (not only X) in

```
/var/log/messages           <-- general status/error reports
/var/log/pm-powersave.log   <-- power management reports
```

and in the files in `/var/log` in general. Is this a laptop? Is your system overheating?

Comment: /var/log/Xorg.0.log seems only to contain information from my current uptime.

Comment: Your question regarding overheating might touch the point. I use an external w-lan stick via usb, and it seems that the freezes correlate with the usb-stick turning palpably warm.